# Passing a Guid through to another page ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, guid

I have a Guid loaded with a ID that a user selected from a GridView.

I want to pass this Guid to another page, but i dont know how to append it to the statement below:

```
    Response.Redirect("LicenseDetailsView.aspx?idLicense="  guidLicense)
```

Here is the full code:

```
    Dim dvrLicense As GridViewRow
    Dim guidLicense As Guid

    dvrLicense = grdAllUserLicense.SelectedRow

    guidLicense = StringToGUID(dvrLicense.Cells(1).Text.ToString)

    Response.Redirect("LicenseDetailsView.aspx?idLicense="  guidLicense)
```

the variable i want to pass is called: guidLicense.

Comment: The string concatenation operator is `&` in VB, right?  Either that or `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a format string:

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("LicenseDetailsView.aspx?idLicense={0}", guidLicense))
```

Or perhaps just concatenate it (though the former is preferred):

```
Response.Redirect("LicenseDetailsView.aspx?idLicense=" & guidLicense)
```

The point being that there has to be some operation performed on the two  values (the string literal and the variable).  Putting them next to each other doesn't mean anything to the compiler.  A method call with the values as arguments, or an operator between the values, will instruct the code to do something with those values.